# Lets say you expand ruby on rails. Is there a good way to dynamically use that code, without having to reinstall all of the gems?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, git

If you are developing the ruby on rails main code base is highly useful to replace the various gems in /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/ with symlinks.

For example, if I have cloned ruby on rails 3.2.0 to /home/me/rails, then to create a symlink at /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/railties-3.2.0 that points to /home/me/rails/railties, and to do this for every needed gem.

This is useful because if you create some feature that you need, then you can try it out right away instead of reinstalling all of the gems. I've created a script that automates this, but I would imagine that there is a better way to accomplish this 'the rails way'.

Answer (score 0):

You can always use the `:path` option in your `Gemfile` to specify the absolute path to any version of Rails you want. This makes your overrides more explicit.

Comment: Won't you have to specify every gem dependency of Rails (e.g., railties) with `:path`, then?

Comment: If you want those to be modded, too, then yes. Otherwise it will install them from the `source` specified.